# Existe alguna manera de refrescar un componente primeface desde una clase anotada como websocket ServerEndpoint

Tags: java, ajax, jsf

Me encuentro desarrollando una aplicación donde desde mi app android desencadene un evento sobre mi aplicación web JSF, la he realizado mediante el uso de websockets.

Mi problema es mostrar los datos que recibe el websocket en mi vista xhtml cuando se ejecuta el método anotado con @onMessage.

A continuación mi clase endpoint

```
 @ServerEndpoint(value = "/despacho")
 public class DespachoNotificationEndPoint implements Serializable{
    public static List<String> listaValores = new ArrayList<>();

    @OnMessage
    public void messageRecive(Session s, String message) {
    getListaValores().add(message);
    System.out.println(message);
    }

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session s) {
    /*código cuando se abre la conexión websocket*/
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session s) {
     /*método cuando se cierra la conexión websocket*/
    }

    public static void resetResource() {
        getListaValores().clear();
    }

    public static List<String> getListaValores() {
        return listaValores;
    }

    public static void setListaValores(List<String> listaValores) {
        DespachoNotificationEndPoint.listaValores = listaValores;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si, tienes que añadir un socket en tu página que escucha en un canal por el que vas a publicar:

*.xhtml

```
<p:socket onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/refreshComp" />

<p:remoteCommand name="updateComp"  update=":component" />


<script type="text/javascript">
     function handleMessage(data) {
             updateComp();
     }
</script>
```

Bean

```
private final EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();

@OnMessage
public void messageRecive(Session s, String message) {
     getListaValores().add(message);
     eventBus.publish("/refreshComp", "");
}
```

En caso de multiples usuarios concurrentes lo ideal es crear un canal univoco para cada cliente, para evitar que se actualicen todos los clientes.

Un saludo